# Submersible well pump randomly tripping thermal protection

Tags: pump, well, protection

I have a 2 year old 4" submersible well pump which sometimes triggers the thermal protection. If I turn it back on, it continues to run properly and at some point (could be hours, could be days, could be weeks) it triggers the thermal protection again.

It never happens to trigger the thermal protection immediately after I just reset it.

Could it be a faulty thermal protection ? Or could it be something else ?

Comment: Low water levels will cause the pump to overheat usually once they kick out the well has had time to recover (fill back up) and cool the motor. Have you had a flow test on your well? A pump that is a bit oversized can cause this problem. Also new homes in the area can lower the static level because of increased usage. These are things that I have found in the past that contributed to random trips. If it becomes a regular issue or tripping on start check the starting capacitor(s) a bad cap can cause overheating in the start circuit and the run circuit if your system has both.

Comment: Thanks @EdBeal , I haven't considered a flow test, I'll look into that! So far the trips have been random. Works for tens of minutes at a time while watering the garden, then tripping, resetting the breaker and then continues to work for other tens of minutes or even days. Today it tripped 3 times, and last time it tripped was over a week ago. It even tripped during heavy storms so I'm not sure if well water level would really be the issue. I'll look into the capacitor and thermal protection and try to change them to see if the issue persists. Thanks!

Comment: It seems the problem was not the low water levels, but a bad thermal breaker. Bought a new one (although not the same brand as the original) and that one broke real quick. Ordered an original thermal breaker now and hopefully this one will work properly. Is it possible that bad wiring or the well pump is damaging the Thermal Protection in any way ?

Comment: The good news is it was failing open that should have protected it from damage where if it failed closed I would expect damage if it was overheating.to see if the pump is the problem I would want to check the current draw to make sure the pump is running close to FLA (full load amperage). If you have the motor information it should provide the FLA or a close value can be looked up by voltage and horsepower.

Comment: Last time I checked, the indicated current was somewhere around 0.2A. I'm not sure if that was an error on my part or my amp measurer was broken, or maybe it was 2A and I set the amp tool to the wrong scale. The max  indicated in the pump specs is 6A. In any case, I assume if the pump was damaged, the breaker would trigger randomly. I'll check the amps tomorrow again just to be sure.

Comment: Just checked, it seems the pump starts at around 5.2A, averaging a 5.5A with peaks at around 5.7A. I've left it running for about 5 minutes continuously and the highest it reached was 5.7A. Would the breaker trip when getting close to 6A although not surpassing it ?

Comment: I am still guessing here without the voltage. 1/4 hp at 115 volt book value is 5.8 amps that is a small pump for most homes. At 230v 1/2 Hp 4.9amps or 3/4 hp at 6.9 so I would guess 1/2 hp but mfg specs can vary from book values. Since your problem is not on start I would guess the system has a run capacitor that is going bad but that is still a guess with the available information.

Comment: The pump specs say 230V, 1HP, 6A (http://www.acqua-service.ro/_upload/products/pdf/1097765966_Jolly-JM.pdf). I've just changed the capacitor that was next to the breaker so that one should be fine (unless the new one came broken). I had to manually tie up the ground cable to the cable that goes in the well to the pump, would a bad connection be able to trigger such events ?

Comment: The 230/240 pumps I have installed only need the ground to provide a path to trip the breaker if the pump fails. The well case should be grounded (may be a local requirement can't remember off the top).  Since it is a 1 hp you are well below what should trip the breaker. Since you just changed the cap that could have been the problem usually motor overload take 10,20,30 seconds at full load or 115% of full load before they open unless it is a direct short then they trip immediately. Caps when going bad may look like a short for a short time no pun intended. You may need to turn it on and watch

Comment: I changed the trip breaker a couple of months ago (and the capacitor along with it), that one worked well for about 2-3 months till it broke at some point (the breaker started making sounds at some point and pressure would go above 1 bar). Waiting for a breaker replacement batch now and was thinking of taking the breaker out till the batch gets here to prevent the pump from from stopping randomly. Still, if it were the capacitor, would it run 30 minutes sometimes while tripping after 1 minute at other times ?

Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: Looking up a 1 hp 230v pump the book value is 8 amps , even going with the 6amp Fla. The overload should be 6.9 amps or 115% . the circuit breaker should be larger to allow in rush or starting current many times 3-5 times the Fla (full load amperage) other than the items you have already changed I am not sure where else to look.

Comment: I ran one more test yesterday and indeed, it seems sometimes it goes to 6A when getting close to 4bars (maximum pressure allowed) and is running for quite some time. I've removed the breaker at the moment till the new ones come and if this still happens, I might look into getting a 7-8A breaker. Worst case scenario, the pump gets burned, or the general breaker trips if there is a significant spike in power consumption. Thanks!